# How can I change height of Navigation Bar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to set height of Navigation bar which I will receive from a web service

Comment: You should create custom navigation bar by `UIView`. Take outlet of height constrains and change constant programatically what you receive from web service.

Comment: Sagar can you please share demo code ?

Answer (score 0):

I have added custom view at top instead of navigation bar and hide default navigation bar. Then set height of that view and took outlet for `height` constraints.

```
@IBOutlet weak var const_customNavBar_height : NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Change it as follow:

```
self.const_customNavBar_height.constant = 105
```

replace `105` with height received in web service.